# .htaccess rewriting not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My current url: http://website.com/user.php?user=jon
What I want it to look like: http://website.com/jon

This is what I currently have in my htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST-FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST-FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST-FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule . user.php?user=%{REQUEST-FILENAME}
```

But it does not work.

Comment: You could also try - RewriteRule (.*) user.php?user=$1

Comment: that works; sort of.
It gets me to the page i want, but it says the user is not in the database.

Comment: can you do a print_r($_GET); on the page that loads and show us the output in your question (maybe even post the code on user.php too)

Comment: I get this `Array ( [user] => /kunden/homepages/34/d584686802/htdocs/my_sm/jon )`

Comment: Can you update the code to show what your htaccess is now? Seems like we might need to change the RewriteBase maybe. Can you also post the entire url you are using to access the page

Comment: `Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule . user.php?user=%{REQUEST_FILENAME}
`

Comment: Please change the last line of the htaccess to RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?user=$1 [NC,L] and see if that works

Comment: That worked!
My FTP must not have gone through last time.

Comment: While I'm here what does the [NC, L] do?

Comment: NC is Case Insensitive so it doesn't really affect this rule. but if you had user(.*) and User(.*) it would make a difference. L means if it fulfills this rule then stop. It stands for Last

Comment: If you feel like my answer was the correct one feel free to accept is at the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your - to _ - it is REQUEST_FILENAME not REQUEST-FILENAME

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule . user.php?user=%{REQUEST_FILENAME}
```

I prefer to use the regex part of the rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Good spot, I saw them as underscores, I would also change the last line to 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?user=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: @JamesLockhart Would you like to make the edit and i'll approve it and you can get some reputation

Answer (score 2):

Do you have AllowOverride enabled for that directory in your virtual hosts or Apache config?

e.g.

```
<Directory "/">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

If not then your local htaccess file will be ignored. Also, do you have mod_rewrite enabled?

If unsure check your Apache log files.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: my host does not allow  me to modify the apache config.
 When I change that last line to `RewriteRule . user.php?user=%jon` it works, but only takes me to that page.